# Word/phrase for something most people have heard of but don't understand

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

I'm thinking of things like general relativity or the Dow Jones Industrial Average.  You have a general idea about what context the name belongs to but probably don't understand it well enough to explain what it is to someone else.  Is there a word or phrase to express that?

Comment: Obscure jargon?

Comment: This could include just about anything in the modern-day environment. Apart from an engineer, who can explain how a cell phone or computer or even a TV works?

Comment: I think jargon is a good one @NVZ!  Although I can't explain how it works I can tell you what a cell phone or a TV is or what it does. Does that make sense @Cascabel?

Comment: I guess it depends on what your idea of "understanding well enough to explain" is. I would not call your examples "jargon".

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Jargon*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jargon)

> noun 1. Special words or expressions used by a profession or group that are difficult for others to understand.

Example: legal jargon, medical jargon

Comment: I'd upvote this, but I don't know if you're going for the **Tenacious** badge. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider ***rocket science***.

ODO:

> **[rocket science](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rocket_science)**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> humorous
>
> *[mass noun, usually with negative]*
>   Something very difficult to
>   understand.
>
> ‘we want you to get out and vote—it's not exactly rocket science’

Answer (score 0):

**Arcane**

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arcane)

> known or knowable only to a few people

I consider this a better answer than jargon, which is terminology peculiar to a field. General relativity does have jargon such as gravitational lensing but it is the concepts that are difficult rather than the words that express them.